# Get Image URL from Rich text Multiline Textbox in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, export-to-excel, multiline

I am using a rich text multiline textbox field in SharePoint 2016 where users can add text & images while submitting the data from a Nintex form. The data is getting saved successfully in a SharePoint List.

**The issue is when users are exporting the data to an excel, only the text is getting exported of the multiline textbox field and not the image. Please suggest if we can get the image also in exported data.**

An early response would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The picture you inserted in the rich text field is stored in another place. When you export the list into excel file, it will only export text in the rich text field. You could use Hyperlink and Picture column to import picture URL from list to Excel file.

Comment: Actually I have used Enhanced Rich text box and the text and image are getting saved in the SharePoint List in the same column (my environment is SharePoint Server 2019 modern experience). When I export the list into excel file, I want the image also (not the hyperlink or URL of the image) to be available in Excel.

Comment: Per my test, it is not possible that when you export the list into excel file, the image will also to be available in excel file.